# How to do task in the background?

Tags: android, background, task

is there a method that I can use to do code when the app is closed? I need to refresh the database and check for incoming polls from other devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a service. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) a starting point for what you'll want to learn. There are many examples and tutorials to be found with a Google search for "android service example"